# Click и возврат

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
Я перекопал кучу сайтов и никак не могу найти работающий код, который при первом клике выполняет указанный код, а при повторном возвращает исходный код.

Помогите. Я новичок в jQuery и у меня уже взрывается мозг.

**Пример кода:**

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#div_for_img img').click(function(eventObject) {
    if (eventObject.shiftKey) {
        $(this).css('border', '4px solid #cc0000');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('border','4px solid #333');
    };
    });
});
```

Это код который выполняется при первом клике, с некоторыми условиями, но, что необходимо добавить, что бы при повторном клике всё возвращалось на исходную позицию.

Благодарю за внимание.
С нетерпением жду ваших вариантов.

Comment: @Oscar_Silliont, у вас два развития событий при клике на изображение: с зажатым shift-ом - цвет рамки обного цвета, и без shift-а - другого цвета. Теперь наводящие вопросы. Что должно происходить при повторном клике? Имеет ли значение зажат shift или нет и какого цвета должна стать рамка в каком случае или она должна просто убираться?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = true;
    $('#div_for_img img').on('click', function(eventObject) {
        if (eventObject.shiftKey && flag) {
            $(this).css('border', '4px solid #cc0000');
            flag = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css('border','4px solid #333');
            flag = true;
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Если шифт нажат, и флага нет, то во вторую ветку попадет.

Comment: Ну да. Я может задачу не правильно понял... При клике с нажатым шифтом переключать стили.

Comment: > но, что необходимо добавить, что бы при **повторном клике** всё возвращалось на исходную позицию.

Comment: Даже в таком случае можно решить задачу с флагом, просто слегка поменяется условие. И нам нужна "исходная позиция".

Comment: Исходная позиция - это полное отсутствие border
$(this).css('border','none');
Спасибо за ответы, очень интересно, но ни не понимаю как написать флаг?

Comment: @Oscar_Silliont, [проверяйте тут][1]. Так вы хотели?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/bLK8z/

Comment: Да. большое спасибо.
суть метода мне понятна.
Запишу, запомню, буду знать.
Очень благодарен.